# Wordpress email post content

Tags: wordpress, email

I have this function in functions.php to send an email when a new post is published.

How can I add the content of the post as the message in the email.

```
function authorNotification($post_id) {

   $to = 'email@hotmail.co.uk';

   $subject = 'New Post';

   $message = $post_id->post_content;

   $headers = 'Content-type: text/html';

   wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
add_action('publish_post', 'authorNotification');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :-

```
function authorNotification($post_id) {

   $to = 'email@hotmail.co.uk';

   $subject = 'New Post';

   $post_obj = get_post($post_id); 
   $postcontent = $post_obj->post_content;

   $message = $postcontent;

   $headers = 'Content-type: text/html';

   wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
add_action('publish_post', 'authorNotification');
```

Comment: Do you know how I might change the email title as it shows up in the mail app from Wordpress to something else.

Comment: you mean wordpress@ ??

Comment: you can do it like below :-
 open /wp-includes/pluggable.php and find wordpress@ and replace wordpress with whatever you like, there are two of them.

Comment: Yes I mean the 'Wordpress <sitename>' at the top of the email - if I change the file you mention will it effect anything else?

Comment: No, it will not affect anything else

Comment: Is there no way of changing this without changing the core files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56201/discussion-between-khushboo-and-ttmt).

Comment: you can use add_filter( 'wp_mail_from', '' ); then